# Specific question on proving continuity of this function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

If $c\in\mathbb{R}$, I want to show that $f(x)=\dfrac{cx}{x^2+c^2}$ is continuous using $\varepsilon-\delta$. Unfortunately from an algebraic standpoint I seem to be missing the strategy. I let $p\in\mathbb{R}$ ($p\neq 0)$, and I want $\forall \varepsilon>0$ $\exists \delta>0$ such that $\left|x-p\right|<\delta \Rightarrow \left|f(x)-f(p)\right|<\varepsilon$.

$\left|f(x)-f(p)\right|=\left|\dfrac{cx}{x^2+c^2}-\dfrac{cp}{p^2+c^2}\right|=|c|\left|\dfrac{x}{x^2+c^2}-\dfrac{p}{p^2+c^2}\right|,$ but I do not see how to proceed.

Comment: Are you assuming that $ x/(x^2+c^2) = 1/x + x/c^2 $ (and likewise for $p$) in step #3 of your chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $\delta < |p|/2$ such that when $|x-p| < \delta$,

$$||x|-|p|| \leq |x-p|< |p|/2$$ 
and
$$|p|/2 <|x| < 3|p|/2$$

Note that

$$|f(x) - f(p)| < \frac{|c||p||x|}{|x^2+c^2||p^2+c^2|}|x-p|+\frac{|c|^3}{|x^2+c^2||p^2+c^2|}|x-p| \\ < \frac{3|c|p^2}{2|p^2/2+c^2||p^2+c^2|}|x-p|+\frac{|c|^3}{|p^2/2+c^2||p^2+c^2|}|x-p|\\ = \left[\frac{3|c|p^2}{2|p^2/2+c^2||p^2+c^2|}+\frac{|c|^3}{|p^2/2+c^2||p^2+c^2|}\right] |x-p|$$

Choose  $\delta'$ such that the RHS is less than $\epsilon$ if $|x-p|< \delta'$:

$$\delta' = \epsilon \left[\frac{3|c|p^2}{2|p^2/2+c^2||p^2+c^2|}+\frac{|c|^3}{|p^2/2+c^2||p^2+c^2|}\right]^{-1}$$

Therefore, if $|x-p| < \min(\delta, \delta')$ then $|f(x) - f(p)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: I have to recheck, but if you get $x$ in the denominator you can use the same argument to get a bound independent of $x$.

Comment: Im adding the explanation -- and I fixed the error after the first line.

Comment: Its $x(p^2+c^2)-p(x^2+c^2)=xp(p-x) + c^2(x-p)$. Then use triangle inequality.

Comment: You're welcome.  Good problem

Comment: We need $|x-p|$ small enough that $|p|/2 < |x| < 3|p|/2$ to bound away the $x$ in the denominator and so that the RHS of the last inequality $< \epsilon$. So $|x-p|$ must be both less than $|p|/2$ and less than $\delta'$ which is less than $\epsilon$ divided by the expression in square brackets.

Comment: I mean the entire RHS after the final = sign.  We want $[ ... + ...]|x-p| < \epsilon$ Let $\delta' = \epsilon/[... + ...]$. Then good things happen when $|x-p| < \delta'$